# Org-Mode: Keep a daily, repeated task marked as done until the next day

Tags: org-mode

I have a checklist of daily tasks like so:

```
* TODO Brush Teeth
SCHEDULED: <2016-05-15 +1d>

* TODO Exercise
SCHEDULED: <2016-05-15 +1d>
```

Normally, if I mark an item as done, org-mode increments the date counter, logs the item as done and keeps the items marked as TODO.

```
* TODO Brush Teeth
DEADLINE: <2016-05-16 Mon +1d>
:PROPERTIES:
:LAST_REPEAT: [2016-05-15 Sun 15:37]
:END:
- State "DONE"       from "TODO"       [2016-05-15 Sun 15:37]
```

Is there a way to keep an item marked as DONE until the next day?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try enabling the `org-habit` module, and then set the `SCHEDULED` property to `SCHEDULED: <2016-05-16 Mon .+1d>` (note the `.` in front of the `+`). See the [Tracking your habits](http://orgmode.org/manual/Tracking-your-habits.html) docs for more info.

And don't forget to brush your teeth!

Comment: Does this really move TODO to DONE for a day, or does it just it just change the way the logging and agenda view works? I was also looking for answer to this, and can't seem to get this answer to work. The "tracking your habits" page doesn't seem to indicate that it will work as desired either. I could well be doing something wrong though...

Comment: The habits works well enough for my use case, but items are still marked as TODO.  I found that it's easier to use agenda views to organize what I'm working on than try to change how repeated items get updated.